# Is there a Playwright method to match Selenium GetDomProperty

Tags: selenium-webdriver, playwright

When using Selenium I sometimes need to use code like

```
_deliveredQty[pos] = double.Parse(element.GetDomProperty("value"));
```

I am struggling to find a method for doing this in Playwright, any ideas please folks

Comment: Happy to help. So your element has a value property and you wish to get its text? I could give you a general approach or something specific if you could share the HTML

Comment: Are you looking for [getAttribute](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-get-attribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getAttribute()`

```js
    const value = await page.locator("yourLocator").getAttribute("value");
    deliveredQty.pos = Number.parseFloat(value);
```

Just rewrite it your language API